# how can i fit the third and 4th li button in the same column

Tags: css, css-grid

[End Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kn2t.png)

[Current progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuEyD.png)

I am trying to have a 4x5 Grid but i want buttons 3 and 4 to fit in one column but unable to figure it out how. i've tried targeting those individual items but was unsuccessfull
can some help

i have removed the images for css and html and inserted the code. i dont use stackoverflow that much so apologies if i am not following the rules

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
div.buttons ul.buttons {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4 1fr);
}

/* Target the C and CE buttons to span half of their respective column */
ul.buttons li:nth-child(3) button,
ul.buttons li:nth-child(4) button {
  grid-column: 3 / 5; /* Start at column line 3 and end at line 5 */
}

ul li button {
  font-size: 1rem; /* Adjust as needed */
  font-weight: bold; /* Adjust as needed */
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px; /* Adjust as needed */
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
//html
 <div class="container">
      <h1>Calculator</h1>
      <div class="input-box">
        <input type="text" placeholder="0" />
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <ul class="buttons">
          <li><button type="button" class="openBracket">(</button></li>
          <li><button type="button" class="closeBracket">)</button></li>
          <li><button type="button" class="c">C</button></li>
          <li><button type="button" class="ce">CE</button></li>
          <li><button type="button" class="divide">%</button></li>
          <li><button type="button" class="7">7</button></li>
          <li><button type="button" class="8">8</button></li>
          <li><button type="button" class="9">9</button></li>
          <li><button type="button" class="x">X</button></li>
          <li><button type="button" class="4">4</button></li>
          <li><button type="button" class="5">5</button></li>
          <li><button type="button" class="6">6</button></li>
          <li><button type="button" class="minus">-</button></li>
          <li><button type="button" class="1">1</button></li>
          <li><button type="button" class="2">2</button></li>
          <li><button type="button" class="3">3</button></li>
          <li><button type="button" class="plus">+</button></li>
          <li><button type="button" class="0">0</button></li>
          <li><button type="button" class="dot">.</button></li>
          <li><button type="button" class="divide">/</button></li>
          <li><button type="button" class="equal">=</button></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D i couldnt find the stack snippet option you recommended

Comment: It's the icon that looks like `<>`

Answer (score 0):

With your structure your CSS Grid should be 8 columns not 4. Just make each button 2 columns wide except for the two you require.

Also note, class names should not start with (or just be) numbers

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 50px 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.buttons {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 12.5%);
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.buttons li {
  grid-column: span 2;
  margin: 0.25em;
}

ul.buttons li:nth-child(3),
ul.buttons li:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column: span 1;
}

ul.buttons li button {
  font-size: 1rem;
  /* Adjust as needed */
  font-weight: bold;
  /* Adjust as needed */
  padding: 15px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Calculator</h1>
  <div class="input-box">
    <input type="text" placeholder="0" />
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <ul class="buttons">
      <li><button type="button" class="openBracket">(</button></li>
      <li><button type="button" class="closeBracket">)</button></li>
      <li><button type="button" class="c">C</button></li>
      <li><button type="button" class="ce">CE</button></li>
      <li><button type="button" class="divide">%</button></li>
      <li><button type="button" class="7">7</button></li>
      <li><button type="button" class="8">8</button></li>
      <li><button type="button" class="9">9</button></li>
      <li><button type="button" class="x">X</button></li>
      <li><button type="button" class="4">4</button></li>
      <li><button type="button" class="5">5</button></li>
      <li><button type="button" class="6">6</button></li>
      <li><button type="button" class="minus">-</button></li>
      <li><button type="button" class="1">1</button></li>
      <li><button type="button" class="2">2</button></li>
      <li><button type="button" class="3">3</button></li>
      <li><button type="button" class="plus">+</button></li>
      <li><button type="button" class="0">0</button></li>
      <li><button type="button" class="dot">.</button></li>
      <li><button type="button" class="divide">/</button></li>
      <li><button type="button" class="equal">=</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```